# How to sync two combobox when the other one changed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox

I have two combobox on the same page( use for easy navigation ) and I want to sync them when one of the combobox was changed.

here is the html for the first selectbox.

```
<select class="alert_frequency">
  <option value="0">Immediately</option>
  <option value="1">Daily</option>
</select>
```

and for the other other one

```
<select class="alert_frequency">
  <option value="0">Immediately</option>
  <option value="1">Daily</option>
</select>
```

-they are just the same

Here is the javascript to turn the two selectbox using jqueryui

```
$('select').combobox();
```

so basically the two selectbox will be converted to a jqueryUI combobox

What would I like to achieve is that when the first combobox is changed the other one should change as well, and vice versa.

Here is my current code (in a separate file):

```
$('.alert_frequency').combobox('destroy').combobox({
        selected: function( event, ui )
        {
            var val = ui.item.value;
            $('.alert_frequency').val( val ).combobox('refresh');
        }
    });
```

It works actually, the value has been set in both combobox but the TEXT isn't.
I'm referring to the original selectbox that was turn to be combobox which is hidden.
For example if I change first combobox to 'Daily', the two selectbox will have a value of 1 but the 2nd combobox will stay as 'Immediately'. get the point? I just want to change the TEXT of the second combobox when the first combobox was selected a value.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution using the one who comment earlier lol. Thanks anyway

Somebody might find it useful:

```
$('.alert_frequency').change(function(){
  $('.alert_frequency').not(this).val( $(this).val() ).combobox('destroy').combobox();
});
```

Comment: I'm don't know jQuery-UI, but I'm sure there's a better way than that.  Also, why use `$(this).val()` when `this.value` works just fine.  jQuery should only be used when it saves code, not when it causes more code to be run.